# Angular Http get method difference between getById and getByName

Tags: json, angular, http, url, get

I am learning the basics of Angular and am currently working on making a REST service using the HttpClient from @angular/common/http.

In many tutorials the first step is making a http.get() call. Usually first the whole list following a http.get() call focused on retrieving only one element. In my example, I have a userList (with users). I have made two methods: getUserById() and getUserByName(). ${this.userUrl} refers to the location of the database (using a JSON file) Below they are displayed:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getUserById(id: number): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.userUrl}/${id}`);
}

getUserByName(name: string): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.userUrl}/?name=${name}`);
}
```

Initially I tried to make the getUserByName() method work via the same way the getUserById(). Thus using:

```
getUserByName(name: string): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.userUrl}/${name}`);
}
```

This didn't work and I received the error statement 404 file not found. This is the json file that I worked with (I have set up a json server so that I could also perform http.delete() methods and so on):

```
{"users": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "James",
  "lastName": "Jameson",
  "dateOfBirth": "10-10-2000",
  "occupation": "Student"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Steven",
  "lastName": "Stevenson",
  "dateOfBirth": "10-10-1990",
  "occupation": "Police officer"
}]}
```

Can anyone explain me why the getUserById methods works using just '/${id}' in the url call and why the getUserByName needs to use '?/name=${name}'?

Comment: Can you post also your code of the rest service? Presumbly written in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1):

if you use:

```
getUserById(id: number): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.userUrl}/${id}`);
}

getUserByName(name: string): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.userUrl}/${name}`);
}
```

and call for exemple /user3262578, it will enter to the first endpoint method which is `getUserById(id)`, you're clearly have ambiguity here. the both methode have the same endpoints.
try to change the second endpoint (getUserByName) to other link like:

```
return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.userUrl}/search/${name}`);
```

Comment: But then why if I comment out the whole getUserById() method the getUserByName() method still gives me an 404 File Not Found Error?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Angular, this is purely a backend endpoint issue.

Test requests to your backend using an HTTP Rest Client such as PostMan.

Once everything is working at the backend as expected, then integrate with Angular.